# Limits of complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Use the epsilon delta definition to show that $\lim_{z \to 1} \dfrac{i\bar{z}}{2}=\dfrac{i}{2}$.

I am not sure how to do this with complex numbers I know I have to do $|z-1|<\delta\implies |f(z)-\dfrac{i}{2}|<\epsilon $. If I make the substitution of $f(z)$ I get

$|\dfrac{i\bar{z}-i}{2}|<\epsilon$ and I really don't know what to do after this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $|\bar{z}|=|z|$ and $\overline{(\frac{a}{b})}=\frac{\bar{a}}{\bar{b}}$,$|\dfrac{i\bar{z}-i}{2}|=|\dfrac{\bar{z}-1}{2}|=|\overline{\left( \dfrac{\bar{z}-1}{2} \right)}|= \dfrac{|z-1|}{2}$. The first equality is due to $|i|=1$. Then select $\delta$ according to $\epsilon$.

Comment: How can you just individually take the modulo of each individual term inside the modulo? So ur saying |z-i| is just |z-1|? I can't follow with your logic

Comment: @adam No, I am saying $|iz-i|=|z-1|$.This is because $|ab|=|a||b|$, where $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$